# Xcode setNavigationBarHidden moves up view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

To explain my problem, I will show you a screenshot of what happens.
After that, I will show the storyboard and the code that I use.
There are actually two problems, which I think are related.

My app UI looks as follows:

[image]

When scrolling down, I get the following behaviour:

[image]

Navigationbar and tabbar disappear, this is desired behaviour.
Note the white bar below the red bar, this is not desired behaviour and I'm not sure where it comes from.

**Edit**
When making the NewsfeedPageCell blue, I get the following:

[image]

When scrolling back to the top, the result is:

[image]

Suddenly the newsfeed rendered is positioned too high.

My storyboard looks as follows:

[image]

The newsfeed rendered is a reusable View that is loaded from an xib.
Edit: the newsfeed **item** cell is a reusable view loaded from an xib. 
As far as I know, I have added all the required anchors in the storyboard.

The code of my Newsfeed class that handles the visibility of the navigationbar and the tabbar on scroll:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    // Remove navigationbar and tabbar on scroll
    if(velocity.y > 0) {
        parentViewController?.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        parentViewController?.tabBarController?.hideTabBarAnimated(hide: true)
    } else {
        parentViewController?.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        parentViewController?.tabBarController?.hideTabBarAnimated(hide: false)
    }
}
```

I've been stuck with this problem for a while.
Any help is appreciated, and if you need more info, please ask.

Edit: The constraints are as follows:

[image]

Constraints for the Newsfeed Pager:

[image]

Edit2: Debug view navbar hidden:

[image]

Debug view without navbar hidden:

[image]

Comment: can you please post a screenshot of your constraints? It seems to top anchor is incorrect

Comment: @TalZion Added the constraints. When I don't change the `setNavigationBarHidden` to false, the constraints don't show any strange behaviour.

Comment: another screenshot please ;-), run the app and start the view debugger, with navbar hidden and without

Comment: The screenshots need to show a 3D stack, so we can know which view/constraint is the issue.  There are a few possible problems here, I just want to make sure which one before posting an answer. In the meantime as a quick fix, set the view,backgroundColor to .red

Comment: @TalZion I edited the screenshots, not sure if it helps. Not sure what you mean with settings background-color to red, the margin will still be there. And after scrolling back upwards (second screenshot debug), the newsfeed now renders too high when the top is reached (it would appear to be the same amount of the white bar though I'm not sure).

Comment: @TalZion I made the NewsfeedPageCell blue, this seems to give an indication. I'll do some research on this (see screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the top anchor of the menu is to the status bar.

Try:

1. Change MenuBar.top to superview.top, instead of Safe Layout.tom
2. As a quick fix:

   ```
    override viewDidLoad() {

          super.viewDidLoad()
         view.backgroundColor = .red /// or the MenuBar backgroundColor tiny color
      }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think y implement all things right.
if you face the problem devices ios 11.0+ then the problem is UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior when navigation bar is hidden which is UIScollView behavior

you need to set

```
self.collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

the default value for it is .automatic so scroll starting after the status bar.

Comment: It doesn't work for me... I've been trying to find logical sense in this interface builder mechanism for litteral days but quite frankly, it is an unintuitive mess.